# I am unable to get matches with capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to swap two matches per line.
In below example for example i'd like to swap `PAG30079XZ` with `2213`

```
AL/PAG31503XZ/ESB/2351/ESB/ABCD/
AR/PAG30079XZ/ESB/2213/ESB/ABCD
BL/PMC16410R7/ESB/1798/ESB/ABCD/
BR/PMC27936XZ/ESB/2444/ESB/ABCD
CL/PMC27377XZ/ESB/2563/ESB/ABCD/
```

I hoped placing the required values in capturing groups would do the trick, but that doesnt work.

So I tried the following:

```
/(PAG30079XZ)(2213)/g
```

The swapping part would then be

```
$1$2
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/1UnYHQ/2)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regexes for this? Seems to me that a simple tokenisation would be more appropriate.

Comment: How are you swapping the captured groups exactly? Also you're capturing the word ESB in your example, which will naturally swap only that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I am not sure what you mean with tokenisation. Do you have an example. I

Comment: Your example doesn't match anything... Did you mean `/(PAG30079XZ)\/ESB\/(2213)/g` and replace it with `$2/ESB/$1`? [example](https://regex101.com/r/1UnYHQ/3)

Comment: @dummy Why not use `str.split('/')` then work with the resulting array elements? That is, swapping element 1 (second) with element 3 (fourth)? I see no need for regexes here; in fact, regexes will only complicate matters. Can you tell us more about why you chose to employ them for this task?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, your task is more general, not limited to a single row and single pair of
strings.

You actually want to swap **second** and **fourth** "segment" of each line,
between `/` chars, in the case of row #2 in your source data,
`PAG30079XZ` and `2213`.

If I am right, use capturing groups for each segment, with `/` between them.
As I see from your data, all segments include letters and digits,
so for simplicity each group can be `\w+` (non-empty sequence of
word chars). `\w` actually matches also `_`, but I think it doesn't matter.

The exception is segment 4, containing only digits, so this group can be
`\d+`.

So the whole regex shold be:

```
^(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+)
```

(note `^` - start of line anchor and quotation of `/`) and the replacement
string should be:

```
$1/$4/$3/$2
```

(note `$2` and `$4` swapped).

You should also use `g` option  to perform global replacement and
`m` to match start of line by `^`.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/D3K837/1

Comment: Regarding `g` and `m` that depends on how the input is delivered, which we don't know. If it's all one string then yes

Comment: From your source data I initially deduced that you have the whole string (a numer of lines with `\n` between them). But if your program receives the input line by line, you can apply the regex to each line separately, without both options. But it will do no harm if you leave them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with a regex, if you provide a pattern that actually matches the input.

Extrapolating your requirement a bit (it was underspecified):

```
str.replace(/^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/ESB\/([^\/]+)\/ESB\/([^\/]+\/?)$/, "$1/$3/ESB/$2/ESB/$4")
```

#### ([live demo](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=106334))

I'm capturing the "things" in between `/` characters (in some cases just sticking with hard-coded "ESB" as I'm assuming that's a constant "anchor", but you didn't say) then re-arranging them in the result.

However, you may find it far simpler to simply tokenise the string using `str.split('/')` then re-arrange the elements of the resulting array however you see fit. There doesn't seem to be a strong use-case for regular expressions here.